# Is it possible to turn off Dramatic Ages or any game mode off Mid game

Tags: civilization-6

I've seen posts about using hex editor to change victory conditions but is it also possible to disable a game mode using this method, if so can any smart person who knows this stuff please help me out.

Comment: Messing with binary data can not only crash the game, but can make the game unrecoverable and un-uninstallable. This is modding btw, modifying game files, which is off-topic.